# solarium-3x and Curl :Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, curl, solarium, cakephp-2.6, solr5

I have to extract rich document and commit using solarium Client php for Apache Solr; in the documentation of solarium Curl is default Adapter then i dont need:

```
$client->setAdapter('Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl');
```

Then I want to force the connection to explicitly close when it has finished processing , Curl will just open another connection when that happens;
 for that i try this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers=array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data',
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'Keep-Alive: 300');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
```

finally execute request:

```
$query->setDocument($doc);

$request = $client->createRequest($query);


$result = $client->executeRequest($request);
```

But after 30 second time out stop the process of indexing .